# How to set a request's limit to a joken JWT

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I'm working in an API with python, flask and implementing JWT with a timeout for expiration, but I'd like to set also a limit request, So the token is gonna be invalid if the time is out or the token has been used in five requests. 
I'd been working with the timeout for expiration, but I can't find how to implement the expiration by five requests. Thanks by the help.

The Code til now:

```
from flask import *
import jwt
import datetime
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from functools import wraps
import hashlib

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'MONGOCONEX'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/MONGOCONEX'
app.config['log_log_1'] = 'LOGKEYCONNECT'
app.config['key1'] = 'SECRECTKEY'
app.config['key2'] = 'PASSKEY'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

def token_required(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    token = request.args.get('token') 
    if not token:
        return jsonify({'error': 402,'message':'Token is missing'})

    try:
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['key1'])
    except:
        return jsonify({'error': 403,'message': 'Token Invalid'})

    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  return decorated


@app.route('/results', methods=['GET'])
@token_required
def get_all_stars():
 results = mongo.db.resultados
 output = []
 date_start = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1*365)
 date_end = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1*365)
 for s in results.find():
  #print(s)
  if date_start <= s['day'] <= date_end:
    output.append({'day':s['day'], 'monthly_prediction':s['monthly_prediction'], 'percent_prediction':s['percent_prediction']})

 return jsonify({'result' : output})


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
  log_key = request.args.get('l_k')
  password_k = request.args.get('p_k')

  md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
  md5_hash.update(b""+app.config['key2']+"")
  encoded_pass_key = md5_hash.hexdigest()

  if (log_key == app.config['log_log_1']) and (password_k == encoded_pass_key):
    token = jwt.encode({'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)}, app.config['key1'])

    return jsonify({'token': token.decode('UTF-8')})

  return jsonify({'error': 401, 'description': 'Not verified', 'Wrong Auth': 'Auth Required'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    app.run(debug=True)
except Exception as e:
    print('Error: '+str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using mongo, the workflow is you can put counter along with the token in mongo database and count it how many it has been used, then adding logic to compare which one comes first, the time limit or how many times the token has been used, if it has been used five times you can revoke the token & generate a new token or another workflow you want to do. Here's the further reference to revoke/blacklist the token after it has been accesed five times https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/blacklist_and_token_revoking/